# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'impassionuser'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, makemigrations

I'm using django on vscode, and typed this on terminal:

```
(impassion) Subinui-MacBook-Pro:impassion_community subin$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

but can't use makemigrations

got this error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'impassionuser'
```

how can I solve this problem?

I'm using MacOSX, VSCode, django 
and setup virtualenv

I expected to see follow  messages

```
Migrations for 'impassionuser':
 impassionuser/migrations/0001_initial.py
 -Create model impassionuser
```

In settings.py, I already added 'impassionuser'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'impassionuser',
    'board'
]
```

Comment: Did you pip install it to a virtual environment? If so, you need to activate your virtual environment with source myvenv/bin/activate. If you haven't set up a virtual environment yet, you might have installed the module in the wrong directory. Make sure to install the module into the main directory of your project.

Comment: first code I wrote on Terminal was   `pip3 install virtualenv` and then `virtualenv impassion`

Comment: Is your app named impassionuser? If yes, make sure you have added it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` of your settings.py file.

Comment: yes I added `impassionuser` to the ` INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your model in admin.py.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import mymodel


admin.site.register(mymodel)
```

Hopefully this will help.

Also check this [Django Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW)